# Flutter function inside shared preferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Hi all i want to execute a function on load of a page and i have set this:

```
void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getPref();
  }

  getPref() async {
    SharedPreferences myPref = await SharedPreferences
        .getInstance();
    setState(() {
      myId = myPref.getString("keyPrefUserId");
      myFullName = myPref.getString("keyPrefDisplayName");
      myAvatar = myPref.getString("keyPrefPhotoUrl");
      customId = myPref.getString("keyPrefUserId");
      isLoading = false;
    });
    await updateFeedNotificationNumber();
  }

  updateFeedNotificationNumber() async{
    QuerySnapshot eventsQuery = await activityFeedRef
        .document(myid)
        .collection('feedItems')
        .where('isRead', isEqualTo: false)
        .getDocuments();
    eventsQuery.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      doc.reference.updateData({'isRead' : true });
    });
  }
```

But it changes to true if i press every page.. not only to this one. Any idea about that?

Comment: What is changed to true ? `isLoading` or `isRead` ?

Comment: isRead is changing even if i press this page or another. I want to change only at this page.

Comment: can you explain in context of what you want to show in the page and how isRead should be updated.

Comment: setState method don' t work when called in initState.

Comment: i want on load of this page to update the collection field at firebase. But it is update even if i load every page. The function updateFeedNotificationNymber() exists only to this page.